# JavaScript: 1544.9 * 1.55 = 2394.5950000000003 Why?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

In Sencha Touch I use number fields to get some values:

```
 var heightInFt = Ext.getCmp('HeightFt').getValue();
 var heightInIn = Ext.getCmp('Height').getValue();

 var totalHeightInFt = (heightInFt * 12) + heightInIn;

 bmrValue = 655 + (4.35 * weightInLb) + (4.7 * totalHeightInFt) - (4.7 * age);

 bmrValue = Math.round(bmrValue * 100) / 100;
```

Then when I multiply

```
 calories = bmrValue * 1.55;
```

I get this result:
     1544.9 * 1.55 = 2394.5950000000003

What am I doing wrong? What should I do in this situation?

Comment: [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Floating point math does this kind of thing. Live with it. Use `Math.round()` and `Math.toFixed()` to drop the unwanted precision.

Comment: what result did you expect?

Comment: So I basically should always round the results???
@CrazyTrain Thank you for the link!

Comment: Its not a global JavaScript problem. It won't apply to Internet Explorer, but happends in Chrome and Firefox.
The explanation would be:

Because fractional values cannot be perfectly represented by floating point   
numbers.